# Django CreateView with signals?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, mixing

I have several models using CreateView:

```
class JsonResponseMixin(object):

    def is_valid(self, form):
        ...
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
    ...

class CarCreate(JsonResponseMixin, CreateView):
    model = Car
    form = CarForm
    success_url = '/success'
```

My problem is how can I send signal like `car_create.send()` in Django CreateView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a custom `CreateView` with `form_valid` sending that signal.